# Adding options to USB Flash Drive's autostart menu

Tags: windows-xp, usb-flash-drive, autorun

When I insert my USB Flash Drive into my computer, I always get this little autostart popup:

[image: autostart]

I was wondering, how to add elements to that list using the autorun.inf file? I know it's possible, because I've seen some programs do that before.

What I tried and didn't work:

```
[autorun]
label=DJDavid98
open=.\GoogleChromePortable\GoogleChromePortable.exe
action=Google Chrome
```

Comment: Have a look at this instructable [How to make an Autorun.inf File](http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-make-an-Autoruninf-File/#step1)

Comment: @Darius Using that exact information, the option doesn't get added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like AutoRun has been completely disabled in all Microsoft OSes in 2009 through a security update: [KB971029](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/971029)

If you've installed this update by letting Windows Update run automatically, that'd be the source of your issue why it doesn't "just work".

Answer (score 1):

You can add a single item, like a setup program, but not multiple items. Microsoft has disabled autorun.inf files for USB drives completely in Windows 7, but as you're using XP, that shouldn't be a problem to you.
A little example (make sure to save this file as autorun.inf, not autorun.inf.txt):

```
[autorun]
open=ProgramToOpen.exe
label=DJDavid
shellexecute=somefile.txt
shellexecute=http://example.com
action=The list name's item
```

All are optional, but you may only use one of each, and I recommend you to choose for open or shellexecute. So copy-pasting this code won't work, as there are 2 shellexecutes. Open is for a executable, and shellexecute is for a file/url.

Comment: Please see my edit.